# Error while using date between in django raw query

Tags: django, date, between

I am always getting this error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Here is my query

```
State.objects.raw('...review_create_date between %s and %s group by error_type',[fromdate,todate])
```

Here `fromdate=2011-05-21` and `todate='2011-05-27'`

The above query executes in mysql prompt but could not able to run in python shell

Please some one help me

Here is the traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1412, in __iter__
 query = iter(self.query)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 73,  in __iter__
 self._execute_query()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 87, in _execute_query
 self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 18, in execute
 sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 216, in last_executed_query
return smart_unicode(sql) % u_params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Can some one help on this? i tried using %%s and %%s%% but i am getting same error

Comment: try '...%s and %s group by error_type' % (fromdate,todate))

Comment: @JamesO: aargh no, definitely not.

Comment: @Vikram: we need to see more detail. Actual code, plus actual traceback.

Comment: Have you tried formatting string like ...objects.raw('your string' % (fromdate, todate) ) just in case there's an internal problem with django? Could you also post the full query?

Comment: I am getting this error in python shell but I am able to render the results in django template... looks strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

**django raw sql query in view**

> I also faced this issue, so I changed the old formatting to new using
> format and it worked for me.

**models.py**

```
class VehicleDamage(models.Model):
    requestdate = models.DateTimeField("requestdate")
    vendor_name = models.CharField("vendor_name", max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        managed=False
```

**views.py**

```
def location_damageReports(request):
    #static date for testing
    date_from = '2019-11-01'
    date_to = '2019-21-01'
    vehicle_damage_reports = VehicleDamage.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM VendorReport_vehicledamage WHERE requestdate BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'".format(date_from, date_to))
    damage_report = DashboardDamageReportSerializer(vehicle_damage_reports, many=True)
    data={"data": damage_report.data}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `?` instead of `%s`.

Comment: I believe `?` is used for generating random results